# Visual Studio 2015 crashes after installing Python Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ptvs

I recently installed visual studio 2015 Community, I wanted to use python with it. So I installed python tools. Now Visual studio crashes every time I try to create a new project.

Comment: I'd suggest reporting this issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS, where the devs of the Python tools will be able to help you.